# textview size match parent not working on card

Tags: java, android

I have a card in a repeater view. There is a text view in the card. I would like to make the textview the full height of the card but if I set height to match parent. It utilises the full screen, not just the card.

What is my mistake or what do I need to add please.

My code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textModCodeView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:text="ONT4101"
        android:background="#999999"
        />
```

Without match parent:

[image]

With match parent

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textModCodeView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:text="ONT4101"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textModuleDescView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textModCodeView"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textEducatorView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textModuleDescView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textModCodeView"
            android:text="Educator: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textNoOfTestView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textEducatorView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textModCodeView"
            android:text="Tests: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textNoOfAssView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textNoOfTestView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textModCodeView"
            android:text="Assignments: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textNoOfPracView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textNoOfAssView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textModCodeView"
            android:text="Practicals: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textNoOfExamView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textNoOfPracView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textModCodeView"
            android:text="Exams: " />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I want the grey box to be the height of the card. I've changed the first screenshot to show you what I kind of want. Thank you

Comment: Provide full xml code

Comment: are you using constraint layout?

Comment: Your `TextView`  wrapped left side with width `120dp`, so it will grow veritcally  . You need to add the whole layout in question . If your Outer layout is `LinearLayout` change its orientation to veritical and `TextView` to `match_parent`width.

Comment: @samirk433 linearlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```